# Why I have one column with white color but all others having colors? What does it mean?

Tags: python, dataframe, colors, spyder

I know that in Spyder each cell in dataframe displayes different color representing the value difference. But I saw in my dataframe there is one column which is completely white with no color corresponding to the values. I am wondering what this means.

I imported the breast cancer data downloaded as csv file from http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/index.php. I added column names to the first row. I am using Spyder (Python 3.7).

```
tf_train = pd.read_csv("bc.csv")
tf_test = pd.read_csv("bc.csv")
n = len(tf_train)
```

I expect no white column since all other columns have color.

I am debuging my program which is to do deep learning. There is en error "ValueError: could not convert string to float: '?'" when doing model.fit. I am not sure if this error came from the white column.

Comment: Your white column probably contains non-numeric data.

Comment: Got it. Thank you!